# Problem in sorting a constructed data

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have following controller code which is used to plot a chart. The code returns all the values correctly, but is not sorting the data despite including **implements Comparable**...Please help.

Controller:

```
public List<OpportunityData> getOpportunityData() {
Map<String, OpportunityData> oppToData = new Map<String, OpportunityData>();
Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;  
AggregateResult[] result = [SELECT Month__c, Year__c, Sum(Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c) Reve, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Goal__c) Gol FROM User_Stats__C 
where ((Month__c = : string.valueof(today.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(today.year()))
OR (Month__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus1.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus1.year()))
OR (Month__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus2.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus2.year()))) 
and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0 GROUP BY Year__c, Month__c ORDER BY Year__c asc, Month__c asc];
for(AggregateResult a : result) {
    OpportunityData opp = new OpportunityData((String)a.get('Month__c'),
                                          (String)a.get('Year__c'),
                                          (Double)a.get('Reve'),
                                          (Double)a.get('Gol'),
                       0);
    oppToData.put((String)a.get('Month__c'), opp);
}

result = [Select Name, Year__c, Month__c, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Plan__c) DisRev From District_Stat__c 
where ((Month__c = : string.valueof(today.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(today.year()))
OR (Month__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus1.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus1.year()))
OR (Month__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus2.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus2.year()))) 
    and Name =: dist and Name != null
    group by Name, Year__c, Month__c ORDER BY Year__c asc, Month__c asc ];
for(AggregateResult a:result) {
    if (!oppToData.containsKey((String) a.get('Month__c'))) {
        OpportunityData opp = new OpportunityData((String)a.get('Month__c'),
            (String)a.get('Year__c'),
            0,
    0,
            (Decimal)a.get('DisRev'));
        oppToData.put((String) a.get('Month__c'), opp);
    } else {
        oppToData.get((String) a.get('Month__c')).DistRev = ((Decimal)a.get('DisRev'))/1000;
    }
}
return oppToData.values();
}

public class OpportunityData implements Comparable
{
public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
return revenueDate-((OpportunityData)o).revenueDate;
}
public Integer month { get; set; }
public Integer year { get; set; }
public String monthString { get; set; }    
public Integer revenueDate { get; set; }     
public Decimal Revenue { get; set; }
public Decimal Goal { get; set; }
public Decimal Attnmnt { get; set; }    
public Decimal DistRev { get; set; } 

public OpportunityData(String Mon, String Yr, Decimal Reve, Decimal Gol, Decimal Disrev) {
this.month = integer.valueof(Mon);
this.year = integer.valueof(Yr);
    this.revenueDate = Year * 100 + month;
monthString = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(System.Date.newInstance(2000, month, 1), System.Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)).formatGMT('MMM');
Revenue = Reve/1000;
Goal = Gol/1000;
Attnmnt = Revenue / Goal * 100;
DistRev = Disrev / 1000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `sort()` on your list to actually sort the data after implementing `Comparable`.

Try replacing:

```
return oppToData.values();
```

With:

```
List<OpportunityData> sortedResult = oppToData.values();
sortedResult.sort();
return sortedResult;
```

Answer (score 2):

The comparable interface requires you to implement the `compareTo()` method, which you are doing.  The issue is you are not implementing that method correctly.  That method returns an integer based on the comparison.  You are subtracting one date from another and trying to return that.

Try something like this in your `compareTo()`

```
public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
      OpportunityData oppData = (OpportunityData)compareTo;
      if (revenueDate == oppData.revenueDate){
          return 0;
      } 
      if (revenueDate > oppData.revenueDate){
          return -1;
      }
      return 1;  
}
```

Comment: If you look at his code you'll notice that `revenueDate` is an `Integer`. So whilst his does not return the ideal values of 1, 0 or -1 it will return an Integer that works for the Comparable interface.